# Bedeutungsunterschied: Auslassungen (Ellipsen) nach Punkt und Doppelpunkt

Tags: difference, meaning-in-context

**Beispiel**

> Ich weiß, was ich tun muss: zum Essen gehen.
>
> Ich weiß, was ich tun muss. Zum Essen gehen.

**Frage**

Wie unterscheiden sich die Konstruktionen in ihrer Bedeutung?

---

Das zweite Beispiel ist genau genommen keine Ellipse, sondern ein infiniter Hauptsatz.

- Bücker, J. (2012). *Sprachhandeln und Sprachwissen: grammatische Konstruktionen im Spannungsfeld von Interaktion und Kognition* (Vol. 11). Walter de Gruyter.
- Fries, Norbert. (1983). *Syntaktische und semantische Studien zum frei verwendeten Infinitiv*. Tübingen: Narr.
- Kwaśniak, R. (2012). *Infinitiv-und Partizipialkonstruktionen: ihre Strukturen und Funktionen am Beispiel Thomas Manns*. Weidler Buchverlag.

Friedrich Maximilian Klinger, *Sturm und Drang*:

> So ganz zum Kind zu werden! Alles golden, alles herrlich und gut! Dieses Schloß bewohnen, Zimmer, Saal, Keller und Stall! – All des bunten, verworrnen, undeutlichen Zeugs!

Comment: Strikt genommen ist "Zum Essen gehen" kein korrekter Satz (fehlendes Subjekt). Insofern ist Version 2 falsch und einzig 1 richtig, da es nur ein Auflistungspunkt ist. "Ich muss tun: zum Essen gehen". Auf der anderen Seite ist es ja so oder so nur eine Ellipse für "(Ich muss) zum Essen gehen" und gerade in der Umgangssprache ist es ganz normal. Insofern gibt es nicht wirklich einen Unterschied zwischen den beiden Formen, außer dass der erste aus formeller Sicht korrekt ist, der zweite eher nicht.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nach meinem Sprachverständnis:

Die erste Version mit dem Doppelpunkt ist eine direkte, unmittelbare Beantwortung der Frage, was zu tun ist: "Wenn die Glocke läutet, muss ich (wie alle anderen auch in diesem Gebäude) zum Essen gehen."

Die zweite Version deutet eine kleine Nachdenkpause und ein bisschen Sarkasmus an, so als ob "Zum Essen gehen" nicht die erwartete Antwort auf die Frage ist:
"Ich weiß, dass es akute Probleme gibt, aber das einzige, was *ich* jetzt tun muss, ist Essen zu gehen, weil ich nämlich Hunger habe und mir eure Probleme egal sind."

Comment: Sehr interessante Antwort. Das heißt, auf den Doppelpunkt folgt die **logische und erwartbare Konsequenz**, auf den Punkt eine "unlogische", konträre, unerwartete Wendung: *obwohl* es Probleme gibt, gehe *ich* jetzt essen.

Comment: @what: Ja genau.

Comment: Man könnte sagen, dass die "unerwartete" (weil inkorrekte) Interpunktion der zweiten Variante ein Stilmittel ist, um die Natur der Antwort anzudeuten - die eben auch "unerwartet" ist.

Answer (score 2):

Schriftsprachlich werden – sofern nicht in Anführungszeichen mündliche Rede wiedergegeben wird – nur vollständige Sätze, die allein stehen können, mit einem Punkt abgeschlossen. Unvollständige Sätze, bspw. ohne finites Verb, werden mit Komma, Semikolon oder Doppelpunkt an einen Hauptsatz (oder einen anderen davon abhängigen Teilsatz) gebunden. Den linken Teil dieser „Satzklammer“ bildet der großgeschriebene Anfangsbuchstabe.

Daneben gibt es durchaus graphostilistische Mittel, die diese Regel überstimmen:

> Worst. Movie. Ever.

Dies ist aber – vor allem außerhalb von Prosa und dort bestimmter Genres – (noch) nicht so verbreitet wie andere Auszeichnungsmöglichkeiten. Es gibt allerdings auch keine allgemein verstandenen Prosodiemarker (wie | und ‖ im IPA).

Damit sieht die **orthographisch zu erwartende, schriftsprachliche Form** so aus:

> Ich weiß, was ich tun muss`:` zum Essen gehen.
>
> Ich weiß, was ich tun muss`,` zum Essen gehen.

Der Doppelpunkt ist gerichtet, während kommaverbundene Teilsätze häufig umgestellt werden können. Daher ist ersterer hier eindeutig vorzuziehen. Ein nicht paariger Gedankenstrich funktioniert ähnlich und ist ebenfalls orthographisch akzeptiert – Auslassungspunkte schon weniger:

> Ich weiß, was ich tun muss `–` zum Essen gehen.
>
> Ich weiß, was ich tun muss `…` zum Essen gehen.

Hiermit kann man versuchen anzuzeigen, dass der rechte Teil unerwartet ist oder einen längeren Denkprozess erfordert hat. Beim Vorlesen sollte eine größere Sprechpause als zwischen Sätzen gemacht werden. Es gibt also einen kleinen Bedeutungsunterschied zwischen Doppelpunkt/Komma und Gedankenstrich/Punkte, aber letztlich sind diese Interpunktionsnuancen so subtil, dass sie von fast allen überlesen werden dürften.

Es bleibt der einfache  Punkt:

> Ich weiß, was ich tun muss`.` Zum Essen gehen.

Das ist eine orthographisch nicht lizenzierte, rein **graphostilistische Variante**. Welche Interpretation sie beim Leser hinterlässt, ist schwierig einzuschätzen. Es könnte einfach für einen Fehler gehalten werden oder aber für ein Anzeichen von Oralität und damit vermutlich – wie der Gedankenstrich – für eine dramaturgische Sprechpause. Damit würde die Bedeutung der Infinitivgruppe hervorgehoben. Das, was getan werden muss, wäre dann wichtiger als das, was gewusst wird, oder dass überhaupt etwas gewusst wird.

### Weitere Überlegungen

Nach einem als Satz(end)zeichen verwendeten Punkt wird stets großgeschrieben. Das gilt im Prinzip auch für die graphisch darauf basierenden Ausrufe- und Fragezeichen, allerdings können die auch als satzinterne Marker verwendet werden, um Phrasen zu betonen („sic!“) oder in Zweifel zu ziehen, während der Punkt sonst v. a. als Abkürzungsmarker dient.

> Ich weiß, was ich tun muss. *zum Essen gehen.

Nach einem Doppelpunkt sollte hingegen genau dann großgeschrieben werden, wenn ein vollständiger Satz folgt. Das passiert recht häufig, da schriftsprachlich Ellipsen oft als defektiv gelten und sie daher vermieden bzw. aufgelöst werden.

> Ich weiß, was ich tun muss: *Zum Essen gehen.
>
> Ich weiß, was ich tun muss: Ich muss zum Essen gehen.
>
> Ich weiß, was ich tun muss: Ich gehe zum Essen.

In diesen Fällen kann der Doppelpunkt auch durch einen Punkt ersetzt werden. Theoretisch könnte man auch ein Semikolon setzen, aber danach wird immer klein weiter geschrieben. Andere (gestelzte) **Umformulierungen** verlangen hingegen diverse Kommata:

> Ich weiß, was ich tun muss, nämlich zum Essen gehen.
>
> Ich weiß, was ich tun muss, und das ist zum Essen gehen.
>
> Ich weiß, was ich tun muss, und das ist(,) zum Essen zu gehen.
>
> Ich weiß, was ich tun muss, ist, zum Essen zu gehen.
>
> Ich weiß, dass, was ich tun muss, ist, zum Essen zu gehen.
>
> Ich weiß, dass ich zum Essen gehen muss.
>
> Ich weiß, ich muss zum Essen gehen.
>
> Ich weiß: ?ich muss zum Essen gehen.
>
> Ich weiß: Ich muss zum Essen gehen.

Comment: Warum erklärst Du mit einem (falschen) englischen Beispiel, wie etwas im Deutschen geschrieben wird?

Comment: Die Variante mit dem Komma ist falsch und schlecht verständlich: "... tun muss, zum Essen gehen." Fehlt da das "um" in der Form von "Ich weiss, was ich tun muss, um zum Essen zu gehen"?

Comment: @Robert, Comic-Book-Guy-Zitate nach diesem Muster werden oft (und mitunter auch auf Deutsch) so wiedergegeben, um die charakteristische Betonung darzustellen, und sind zwar oberflächlich besehen orthographisch falsch, aber graphostilistisch einfach zu erklären, also auf einer höheren Ebene, vgl. _Title Case_. Für das Komma siehe die Variante mit _nämlich_, welches weggelassen werden kann.

Comment: @Robert Man kann Ellipsen durchaus neben einem Doppelpunkt oder einem Gedankenstrich auch mit einem Komma anführen, das ist immer noch besser als ein Punkt. (die Downvotes hier sind mir übrigens ein Rätsel)

Comment: Diese Antwort geht an der Frage vorbei. Die grammatische Korrektheit, bzw. mögliche Formen sind für die Frage irrelevant.

Comment: @Vogel612 Doch, natürlich hat die **orthographische** Korrektheit etwas mit der Beantwortung zu tun. Ein Leser kann die Punktversion einfach für einen Fehler halten, dann hat sie keinerlei andere Bedeutung als die Doppelpunktversion, oder für ein (noch) nicht konventionelles Indiz für Mündlichkeit und damit für ein Pausezeichen. Die Lesepause kann die Bedeutung verändern, wenn auch nicht wirklich stark. Ich habe versucht zu zeigen, dass es auch andere Lösungen mit ähnlichem Resultat gibt.

Comment: Entweder hatte ich noch nicht genügend Kaffee oder deine Antwort ist nur schwer in diesem Sinne zu verstehen... Ich sehe hier einen langen und breiten Erguss zur Grammatikialität :(

Comment: @Vogel612 Ich werde die Antwort etwas überarbeiten.

Comment: Re: "orthographisch nicht lizensiert". Von wem? Bitte belegen, wo diese Art der Ellipse verboten wird.

Comment: @what „[Punkt] steht nach einem abgeschlossenen [auch mehrteiligen] Ganzsatz“ [Duden: Regel 152f](http://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/punkt), zum Doppelpunkt [R43](http://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/gedankenstrich). Das war jetzt die am einfachsten aufzufindende Quelle einer bekannten Autorität, wobei ich diese Regelformulierungen und ihre Organisation sehr zu recht kritisieren kann.

Comment: Dann schreibt Goethe falsch! "Der Abschied, wie bedrängt, wie trübe!" Keine finite Verbform. Und diesen Legastheniker halten die Deutschen für ihren größten Dichter?

Comment: @what Als Dichter hat er (bzw. sein Verleger) selbstredend alle künstlerischen Freiheiten – und in dem Zitat steht kein Punkt am Ende! Auch bei der schriftlichen Wiedergabe mündlicher Rede gelten eigene Konventionen, wie ich zumindest andeutungsweise versucht habe zu zeigen.

Comment: Am Ende des Goethe-Zitats steht ein Ausrufezeichen. Damit wird im Deutsche ein Satzende gekennzeichnet.

Comment: @what Ausrufe- und Fragezeichen funktionieren **nicht** exakt genauso wie der Punkt. Das habe ich schon am Anfang des Abschnitts „Weitere Überlegungen“ angedeutet. Sie sind außerdem im Rahmen der schriftlichen Wiedergabe mündlicher Rede deutlich häufiger als sonst.

Answer (score 0):

Ohne auf die grammatikalische Besonderheit eines unvollständigen Satzes näher eingehen zu wollen, kann man doch festhalten, dass der gewählten Interpunktion eine stilistische Funktion innewohnt:

## `: – ,`

Mit dem Doppelpunkt, dem Gedankenstrich oder einem Komma stellt man einen Bezug zum vorhergehenden Satzteil her. Die nachfolgende Aussage erhält dadurch eine Verbindung zum zuvor Gesagten. Einen weiteren Bedeutungsunterschied zwischen diesen Satzzeichen kann ich nicht feststellen.

## `.`

Ein Punkt trennt eine Aussage vom nachfolgenden Satz oder Teilsatz. Ein direkter Bezug wird somit stilistisch nicht hergestellt. Nun kann es der übrige Kontext ergeben, dass eine identische Bedeutung besteht wie oben. Ohne oder in einem anderen Kontext kann aber auch ein von der ersten Aussage unabhängiger oder weitgehend unabhängiger Bezug vorliegen.

## `?`

Ein Fragezeichen generiert aus dem ersten Satz eine (rhetorische) Frage, die mit dem nachfolgenden beantwortet ist. Zunächst lässt die Frage aber den Ausgang offen, es wird also stilistisch Spannung erzeugt.

## `!`

Mit dem Ausrufezeichen verändert sich der erste Satzteil dahingehend, dass ihm nun ein unvermittelter oder plötzlicher Charakter zukommt, ähnlich eines plötzlichen Einfalls nach vorangehender Überlegung. Die folgende Aussage erhält dadurch gleichfalls einen unvermittelten Charakter: Es ist der plötzliche Einfall, der hier also näher mit dem vorangehenden Satz verbunden ist als durch einen Doppelpunkt, Komma oder Gedankenstrich.

Comment: Yeah, und dadurch eben entsteht Bedeutung. Wenn die Schlussfolgerung durch einen Doppelpunkt mit dem Bezugssatz verbunden wird, dann erscheint das folgerichtig, weshalb der Satz "at face value" genommen wird. Wird ein Satz, der seinem Kontext nach eine Schlussfolgerung sein muss, dagegen entgegen der Konvention durch einen Punkt von seinem Bezugssatz abgetrennt, dann versucht der Leser diesem Bruch eine Bedeutung zuzumessen. Die genaue Bedeutung wird vom Kontext abhängen, immer aber wird der Leser vermuten, dass an der Schlussfolgerung "etwas faul" ist.

Comment: +1 für "Doppelpunkt stellt Bezug her, Punkt trennt".